# XPATH select random number of nodes AND have multiple conditions

Tags: xpath, random, conditional-statements

I need to select a random number of product details from XML and have multiple conditions.

The below selects 8 products, but they are not random - how to make this random?

> $randomProducts = $prod_xml->xpath("/products/product[position()<
>   9]");

The below makes a selection on multiple conditions.

> $featuredProducts = $prod_xml->xpath('/products/product[featured =1
>   and hidden !=1]');

How do I combine the two to get random featured products that are not set to hidden?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on whether you want first to get all non-hidden and featured products an *then* select 8 of them, or get 8 products and then select all of them that are featured and non-hidden, you will have two different XPath expressions:

```
/products/product[featured =1 and hidden !=1][position() < 9]
```

and correspondingly:

```
/products/product[position() < 9][featured =1 and hidden !=1]
```

Now, the "random" part ...

Neither XPath 1.0 nor XPath 2.0 (or even the W3C working drafts for XPath 3.0 and its standard functions) have a function that returns a pseudo-random sequence of integers (or of anything).

Therefore, you have to form this sequence of eight pseudorandoms and generate an XPath expression as this:

```
/products/product[featured =1 and hidden !=1]
           [contains('|3|5|12|19|4|23|11|7|', concat('|',position(),'|)) ]
```